# Is there any short cut key in Chrome Browser to Clear Cache ...? It is difficult to every time go to settings and clear the content

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

When I develop Wordpress Sites, sometimes cache memory does not get cleared even I hard refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1) With Chrome open, enter 'ctrl' + 'shift' + 'I' to bring up the developer console.
2) Click on the 'network' tab and then click on the 'Disable cache' checkbox.

Then you should get a fresh copy of the page from the server each time you reload it.

Comment: This is the best thnxxx

Answer (score 0):

with chrome open - click 'ctrl+shift+delete' to get clear browsing data console.
check only 'cached images and files' then click 'clear browsing data'.
the selection in the console will be remembered so no need to worry about selecting checkboxes again.

Comment: can you please give it for Mac ... thnxx